# inline backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In C# I have two blocks of code which open and write to processes which I open and I'd like them to run at the same time in the same function. 
I found [BackgroundWorker with anonymous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077762/backgroundworker-with-anonymous-methods) but when i tried to impliment the it doesn't run the code in the lambda expression.

```
BackgroundWorker bgwanalysis = new BackgroundWorker();
bgwanalysis.DoWork += delegate
{
 ...codehere..
};

while (bgwanalysis.IsBusy)
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

I know I'm missing something basic could someone fill me in?
Thanks

Comment: "the code broke" is not a good clue to let us understand what happens on your PC. More details are needed.

Comment: @Steve thanks steve I added it doesnt run the code in the lamda expression sorry i forgot to say that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you're showing, I'm not seeing the line:

```
bgwanalysis.RunWorkerAsync();
```

So your code becomes:

```
BackgroundWorker bgwanalysis = new BackgroundWorker();
bgwanalysis.DoWork += delegate
{
 ...codehere..
};

bgwanalysis.RunWorkerAsync();

while (bgwanalysis.IsBusy)
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```